# Create DateTimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am having a hard time using panda for the first time

I have a dataframe containing year, month, day and hour in separated columns.

As far as i know, this dataframe is not indexed.

I am trying to create a datetime index to this dataframe:

```
def createTimeStamp(year, month, day, hour): 
    return DatetimeIndex(datetime(.........))

df['TimeStamp'] = df.apply(createTimeStamp(df['year'], df['month'], df['day'], df['hour']))

df.set_index('TimeStamp')
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016], 
                   'month': [12, 1], 
                   'day': [31, 1], 
                   'hour': [23, 1]})

# returns datetime objects
df['Timestamp'] = df.apply(lambda row: dt.datetime(row.year, row.month, row.day, row.hour), 
                           axis=1)

# converts to pandas timestamps if desired
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)

>>> df
   day  hour  month  year           Timestamp
0   31    23     12  2015 2015-12-31 23:00:00
1    1     1      1  2016 2016-01-01 01:00:00

# Create a DatetimeIndex and assign it to the dataframe.
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Timestamp)

>>> df
                     day  hour  month  year           Timestamp
2015-12-31 23:00:00   31    23     12  2015 2015-12-31 23:00:00
2016-01-01 01:00:00    1     1      1  2016 2016-01-01 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that set_index modifies a copy of the DataFrame.  If you pass inplace=True to set_index the original DataFrame will be updated.  Alternatively the DataFrame can be reassigned if more operations are needed

`df.set_index('TimeStamp', inplace=True)`
or
`df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')`

Comment: set_index comment was relevent to this question